# How to handle PostBack inside ASP.net Custom Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

May be I am missing something important in order to implement CustomControl properly as per requirement or having a lack of knowledge. Actually I have Created CustomControl (.dll)for searching purpose having 3 Dropdown boxes(populating from database), 1 textbox and search button, after choosing appropriate filter criteria user clicks on Search button and simple gridview appears. My problem is I dont want to fill dropdown boxes in CustomControl on every post back(fired from page).

Comment: Do you check the `IsPostback` property in the control on `Page_Load`?

Comment: I am not getting IsPostback property, I implemented override void OnInit(EventArgs e) & 
override void CreateChildControls()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are in a place that can not spot the `Page` you can use this global parameter:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current
```

Now from that you can get the `Page` if its available,

```
Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;

if (page != null && page.IsPostBack)
{

}
```

or you can get the Form and the post back values using

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form
```

and check if the Form have values, then is probably post back.

Just a note, always check if the `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` **is not null** before using it, because if you call it from a thread and there is no page available, then is `null`.

Comment: Hi Aristos! thanks for your answer, now I am getting PostBack, but my problem was as it is, when second time CreateChildControls() calls, if doesn't load values in dropdown boxes, it gets lost.

Comment: @VishwanathMishra Maybe then the viewstate for this control, when they use it, is disabled. (or you did not save on viewstate this controls)